# Разница между двумя настройками компоновщика в MSVS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Обьясните чем отличаются в MSVS параметры:
Компоновщик/Ввод/Дополнительные зависимости
Компоновщик/общие/Дополнительные каталоги библиотек
Вот у меня есть lib. их и там и там указывать надо?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/linker-property-pages?view=msvc-170#input-property-page

Comment: @user7860670 наверное я не просто так вопрос задал и уж наверное предварительно посмотрел

Comment: Второе - для путей к папкам, чтобы в первом можно было писать не полный путь, а просто имя.

Comment: Если бы это действительно было так, то вопрос бы явно не возник. А если бы и возник, то в нем были какие-то пояснения, что осталось непонятным после чтения документации. Причем скорее всего с цитатами вида "вот по ссылке сказано то-то, а то-то осталось непроясненным".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat т.е из дополнительного каталога он возьмет ттолько те lib, которые явно указаны в дополнительных зависимостях?

Comment: Я думаю что да. Можно поэкспериментировать на всякий.